# Runtime error when creating a constructor for my viewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, web-config

I have designed a simple UI that displays connection strings read from a web.config file.  I have followed the MVVM light framework fairly close and when I instantiate my ConnectionStringViewModel, I get the error.  If I take it out, things work but then I can't reach the data I need to display.  Here is some code:

Connection String ViewModel:

```
public string SqlConnectionString
{
    get { return _sqlConnString; }
    set
    {
        if (_sqlConnString == value)
            return;
        _sqlConnString = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(SqlConnString);
    }
}

public ConnectionStringViewModel(*IValidationService validationService*)
{
    _validationService = validationService;
    _validationService.SqlConnectionStringService(
        (item, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                // Report error here
                return;
            }
            SqlConnectionString = item.ConnString;
        });
}
```

ValidationService:

```
public class ValidationService : IValidationService
{
    private readonly Configuration _webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"C:\Source\web.config");

    public void SqlConnectionStringService(Action<ConnectionString, Exception> callback)
    {
        var connString = new ConnectionString(_webConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        callback(connString, null);
    }
}
```

IValidationService:

```
public interface IValidationService
{
    void SqlConnectionStringService(Action<ConnectionString, Exception> callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With DI you want to avoid executing methods in your constructors. This is because it's possible the DI bootstrapper hasn't finished mapping yet and could cause NullReference exceptions.

You don't say what the exception is so hard to say.

Comment: System.Reflection.TartgetInvocationException  Specifically, "InnerException: Type not found in cache"